# SQL Warning Code: 1364, SQLState: HY000 Field 'district_code' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have Lawyer, Country, State, City and District table in which I have create one extra table named as `lawyer_cscd` which contain the foreign key relation of mentioned above tables name.

Actually Country State City and District will have already prefilled data all I have to do is to get the data from these and associate with the lawyer for that purpose I have created extra table called lawyer_cscd which will have foreign key relation with all five tables,

When I tried to insert the data into lawyer table I got the error

```
 Field 'district_code' doesn't have a default value
```

Below is my classes

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "lawyer")
public class Lawyer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lawyer_batch_no")
    private int lawyerbatchNo;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Universities.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_universities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", nullable = true), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "university_code", nullable = true))
    private List<Universities> universities = new ArrayList<Universities>();

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = LmsUser.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private LmsUser registered_User = new LmsUser();

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code") })
    private Country country;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = State.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "state_code", referencedColumnName = "state_code") })
    private State state;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = City.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "city_code", referencedColumnName = "city_code") })
    private City city;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = District.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "district_code", referencedColumnName = "district_code") })
    private District district;
setter getter....
}
```

District Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "district")
public class District {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "district_code")
    protected String district_code;

    @Column(name = "abbreviation")
    protected String abbreviation;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, targetEntity = City.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
    protected City city;


    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Lawyer.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "district_code", referencedColumnName = "district_code") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") })
    private Set<Lawyer> lawyers=new HashSet<Lawyer>();
}
```

The same for country and state,city we have pozo classes

Testing class

```
class Testing {
public static void main(String args[]){
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("persistentContext.xml");

        RegistrationDao dao = (RegistrationDao) applicationContext.getBean("registrationDaoImpl");
        LmsUser lmsUser = new LmsUser();
        lmsUser.setUser_id(2323l);
        lmsUser.setEmail("hiran17@gmail.com");
        lmsUser.setLast_Login(new Date());
        lmsUser.setStatus(UserStatus.active);
        dao.saveUser(lmsUser);

        Lawyer lawyer = new Lawyer();
        lawyer.setFirstName("sofi");
        lawyer.setLastName("gupta");
        lawyer.setDateOfBirth(new Date());

        AreaOfPractise dowry = new AreaOfPractise();
        dowry.setActive(true);
        dowry.setPractiseName("Murder");
        AreaOfPractise murder = new AreaOfPractise();
        murder.setActive(false);
        murder.setPractiseName("murder");
        lawyer.getAreaOfPractises().add(dowry);
        lawyer.getAreaOfPractises().add(murder);

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setActive(true);
        address.setAddressLine1("khini naka phoota kuwan");
        address.setAddressLine2("Kanpur");
        address.setAddressLine3("Up");
        address.setCity("Uttar Pradesh");
        address.setPostalCode("210001");
        address.setLawyer(lawyer);

        Universities universities = new Universities();
        // universities.setUniversity_code("1213");
        universities.setUniversityName("Uttar Pradesh Technical University");
        universities.setUniversityAddress(address);
        College colleges = new College();
        colleges.setCollege_code("DSI");
        colleges.setCollegeName("DSiTM");
        colleges.setCollegeType(CollegeType.LAW);
        colleges.setCollegeAddress(address);
        colleges.setUniversities(universities);
        universities.getColleges().add(colleges);
        universities.getLawyer().add(lawyer);
        lawyer.setRegistered_User(lmsUser);
        lawyer.getUniversities().add(universities);

        ExperienceSummary experienceSummary = new ExperienceSummary();
        experienceSummary.setLawyer(lawyer);
        experienceSummary.setNoOfCaseInProgress(45);
        lawyer.setExperienceSummary(experienceSummary);

        /*LawyerDao lawyerdao = (LawyerDao) applicationContext.getBean("lawyerDaoImpl");
        lawyerdao.saveLayer(lawyer);
        for (Lawyer string1 : lawyerdao.getLawyersByName("ankur", "jadiya")) {
            System.out.println(string1.getLawyerbatchNo());
            string1.getUniversities().size();
            for (Universities string : string1.getUniversities()) {
                System.out.println(string.getUniversityName());
            }
        }
*/
        CommonDao commonDao = (CommonDao) applicationContext.getBean("commonDaoImpl");

        Country country = new Country();
        country.setCountry_code("IND");
        country.setAbbreviation("IND");
        country.setName("India");
        State state = new State();
        state.setState_code("UP");
        state.setAbbreviation("UP");
        state.setName("Uttar Pradesh");
        state.setCountry(country);
        City city = new City();
        city.setCity_code("BNDA");
        city.setCityName("Banda");


        District district = new District();
        district.setDistrict_code("MUA");
        district.setName("MAHUA");
        district.setCity(city);
        city.getDistricts().add(district);
        District district1 = new District();
        district1.setDistrict_code("MAHOBA");
        district1.setName("MAHOBA");
        district1.setCity(city);
        city.setState(state);
        city.getDistricts().add(district1);
        state.getCity().add(city);
        City city1 = new City();
        city1.setCity_code("CNB");
        city1.setCityName("Kanpur");
        city1.setState(state);
        state.getCity().add(city1);
        City city2 = new City();
        city2.setCity_code("LKO");
        city2.setCityName("Lucknow");
        city2.setState(state);
        state.getCity().add(city2);

        country.getState().add(state);
        district.getLawyers().add(lawyer);
        city.getLawyers().add(lawyer);
        state.getLawyers().add(lawyer);
        country.getLawyers().add(lawyer);
        lawyer.setCountry(country);
        lawyer.setState(state);
        lawyer.setCity(city);
        lawyer.setDistrict(district);

        commonDao.saveCountry(country);

        LawyerDao clawDao = (LawyerDaoImpl) applicationContext.getBean("lawyerDaoImpl");
        clawDao.saveLayer(lawyer);

}

}
```

Comment: You are trying to insert a 'district_code' value null but you have declare that this column is not null or you have constrains that require that this value is not null

Comment: @scaisEdge if you see this line  lawyer.setDistrict(district); I am setting the value of district in lawyer pozo and district.getLawyers().add(lawyer); both ways I have provided the value but while saving clawDao.saveLayer(lawyer) still throwing error not sure why its taking null

Comment: @scaisEdge I am trying this from past 4 days not able to understand what is the mistake I have done

Comment: I have posted  an asnwer  hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a `'district_code'` value null but you have declare that this column is not null  or you have constrains that require that this value is not null

In you save district

```
 lawyer.setDistrict(district);
```

and after

```
 clawDao.saveLayer(lawyer);
```

but you are setted distric1  not district

```
    District district1 = new District();
    district1.setDistrict_code("MAHOBA");
    district1.setName("MAHOBA");
    district1.setCity(city);
```

Comment: I have completely removed the district1 object itself and provided only district but still error is coming

Comment: have you properly setted  district  now..    .. (in the previos code  .. you could try assign distrci1 to lawyer.setDistrict(district1);

Comment: Yes I have completely remove the district1 itself and only using district reference variable lawyer.setDistrict(district) and district.getLawyers().add(lawyer);

Comment: FYI create table lawyer_cscd (city_code varchar(255), country_code varchar(255), district_code varchar(255), state_code varchar(255), lawyer_batch_no integer not null, primary key (district_code, lawyer_batch_no))  why district_code is becoming primary key here while creating the table however city state country also all are having same configuration as district

Comment: then  in your table definition try adding a default value for district_code .. (also an empty varchar ..) seems that som internal trigger check for this  .. and fail ..

Comment: I see  insert query in only accepting two value instead of 5 insert into lawyer_cscd (state_code, lawyer_batch_no) values (?, ?) why so

Comment: Actually lawyer_cscd is the extra table where we have 5 fields ideally when we save the lawyer it should save the state city district country and lawyer_batch_no in the table but its only saving state and lawyer batch no,  rest of the fields are not saving even though I have provided the reference to the lawyer object if you see insert command hibernate is providing state and lawyer batch number only in insert command

Comment: I'm not in your logic and i'm not able actually of provide a real help to your question  ..so  a few minutes and i remove my answer  so eventually someone else can try to help you i a better way ..